# C# Unity - Parent position shifts after I add childs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am adding 10 childs to a empty GameObject in 2D. The empty GameObject has a position of 0,0,0.

When I add the 10 childs his position shifts only in the game view/scene to 4.5 on the X axys, but in the inspector still says that he is in the 0,0,0.

If I open the scene he is in the middle of the childs if I shift he backwards to the center now the inspector reads -4.5,0,0.

Anyone knows how to fix the issue?

Here is the code:

```
int sizeX = 10;
int sizeY = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeX ; i++)  {
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeY; j++)  {
        Instantiate(blocks[Random.Range(0, blocks.Length)], 
                    new Vector2( i,(transform.position.y - j)/2),
                    Quaternion.identity,transform);                 
    }            
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Empty gameObject will stay in 0,0,0 unless you change it manually or with script.

your scene display the centered pivot, not the real pivot, it centered because you have child, so the pivot for transform manipulator tool has changed to bound to the child.

> hit Z on the Keyboard to toggle Pivot Mode, or X to toggle pivot
>   rotation.

Please read the documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html

Comment: Yes that was it, sorry for the trouble.